# Java Accessibility: Emulate ARIA role "alert"

Tags: java, accessibility

I'm writing a Java app and I'm making sure that every bit of it is compatible with screen readers. Having worked with screen readers in the past when doing web development, I assumed, perhaps foolishly, that the behaviour would be much the same in Java.

What I'm particularly struggling with is with providing alert text **without** popping up a dialog. I am providing a status update which is useful information but doesn't require any user interaction.

In a browser, all I had to do was give a DIV the ARIA role "alert" ([Alert Role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/alert_role)).

Now I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with Swing components but I don't see any clear way to do it. The Java accessibility package has an Alert role ([AccessibleRole class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/accessibility/AccessibleRole.html)) whose description suggests the same behaviour but I don't see any Swing components that use it or a way to make them change roles (seems to be hard-coded).

The [How to Support Assistive Technologies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/access.html#accessiblecomponents) guide touches on the idea of creating custom components but barely scratches the surface and doesn't seem to mention the Alert class.

Any idea what some good next steps might be?

Comment: Interesting question, but probably on the border of getting close voted as too unspecific or maybe opinionated. Out of curiosity: why did you choose Java Swing, when a key requirement is accessibility? Meaning: few people do *new* stuff with Swing these days, they rather use frameworks that allows them to well, use nice web frontend technology connected to a java backend ... probably for such reasons. Honestly, when you did proper research, and didn't find your answers, I somehow doubt that Swing works well for accessibility then. You see, those two topics are both so basic ...

Comment: that when you can't find proper guides/tutorials, then probably because: they really dont exist. Depending on your requirements, I would seriously consider to step back from Swing, and use some more up to date framework, instead of a "fat" local GUI client.

Comment: @GhostCat Excellent idea! Before getting into Swing (which seemed to suggest, by all descriptions, that it was accessible and that it works with both NVDA and JAWS), I began by looking into the Java WebView but didn't see any clear sign that it supported accessible web standards. Was I mistaken or are you thinking of some other frontend? Perhaps you could provide specific suggestions?

Comment: What I mean is: you don't do client in java at all any more. You could look at Vaadin for example, but in the end: this really depends on the your exact requirements. What sort of devices you want to support, what functionality the clients need etc pp. That is the point: such *discussions* isn't the purpose/scope of this community. You might rather look around on reddit or quora maybe.

Comment: As far as I remember, you have to implement an interface called Accessible, and then call setAccessible on your component. The Accessible interface allows you to set accessible text, description, role and more. However, as already said, Swing is totally outdated. Maybe you have better chances with SVT from IBM/eclipse, but I don't know if SVT is still actively maintained either.

Comment: @QuentinC A good answer and a fair observation. I honestly wasn't aware that Swing was so outmoded.

Comment: Would either of you care to summarize your response in an answer so I can accept it?